# tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam optimizer object not giving error when using "minimize" function

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

I'm working on linear regression problem using 'keras' but when I try to use the function "minimize" for the "Adam optimizer" object,I get the following error.

> AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'minimize'

This function can be found in the official documentation at :
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam#minimize
and the code can also be found at 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L289-L318

my code is given below

```
     # Initialize an adam optimizer
from  tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam

    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.5)

    for j in range(100):
        opt.minimize(lambda: loss_function(intercept, slope), var_list=[intercept, slope])

    # Apply minimize, pass the loss function, and supply the variables

        # Print every 10th value of the loss
        if j % 10 == 0:
            print(loss_function(intercept, slope).numpy())

    # Plot data and regression line
    plot_results(intercept, slope)
```

why  cant  I use the minimize function for the above Adam object?

Note : linear_regression and loss_function are two functions already defined as below.

```
def linear_regression(intercept,slope,features=x):
    return feautres*slope + intercept
def loss_function(intercept,slope,features=x,target=price):
    predictions=linear_regression(intercept,slope)
    return tf.keras.losses.mse(target,predictions)
```

Comment: The error speaks for itself, looking at the documentation, there's no function `minimize`: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L467

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L289-L318 but it shows the minimize function. Also it can be found https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam#minimize

Comment: Can you show what version of tf and keras you are using?

Comment: version for keras =2.2.4-tf and version for tensorflow=1.13.1

Comment: You need to use tf2 to have the functions you provided by link :)